# Dirport / Orport stop being unreachable after some time

Tags: configuration, relays, help, network-configuration

Just set up a Tor relay on Digital Ocean running Ubuntu 16.04 using tor-relay.co and everything is seemingly going well. However, every so often the relay will cease to work and I'll get the following error:

> [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client
>   functionality is working.
>
> [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
>
> [notice] Now checking whether ORPort x.x.x.x:9001 and DirPort x.x.x.x:9030 are reachable... (this may take up to 20 minutes -- look for log messages indicating success)
>
> [warn] Your server (x.x.x.x:9030) has not managed to confirm that its DirPort is reachable. Relays do not publish descriptors until
>   their ORPort and DirPort are reachable. Please check your firewalls,
>   ports, address, /etc/hosts file, etc.

So far I've been able to remedy the problem by restarting Tor but soon after I start getting the error again.

Here's /etc/tor/torrc:

```
 DisableDebuggerAttachment 0
 ContactInfo blah
 ORPort 9001
 SocksPort 0
 RelayBandwidthBurst 1073741824
 ControlPort 9051
 Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
 ExitPolicy reject *:*
 DirPort 9030
 RelayBandwidthRate 1073741824
 RunAsDaemon 0
 Nickname HelloNSA
```

Output of netstat -lntu:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 172.16.0.1:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9051          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9030            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 fcaa::1:53              :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4500            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:500             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 172.16.0.1:53           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 :::4500                 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::500                  :::*                               
udp6       0      0 fcaa::1:53              :::*
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time tor starts it does a process of connecting and verifying ports. It will try to reach the ports for about 20 minites, and if it cant reach them will throw that error.

Have you opened the ports on the os firewall? Not familiar with digital ocean, but mabey they have some kind of control panel where you have to open ports?